# C#'s switch statement is case-sensitive. Is there a way to toggle it so it becomes case-insensitive?

Tags: c#, switch-statement, case-sensitive

C#'s switch() statement is case-sensitive.  Is there a way to toggle it so it becomes case-insensitive?

==============================

Thanks,
But , I don't like these solutions;

Because case conditions will be a variable , and I don't know if they ALL are UPPER or lower.

Comment: 'case conditions will be variable' - I thought they are compile time constant expressions!

Answer (score 20):

Yes - use `ToLower()` or `ToLowerInvariant()` on its operands. For example:

```
switch(month.ToLower()) {
    case "jan":
    case "january": // These all have to be in lowercase
         // Do something
         break;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do something like this

```
switch(yourStringVariable.ToUpper()){
    case "YOUR_CASE_COND_1":
     // Do your Case1
    break;

    case "YOUR_CASE_COND_2":
    // Do your Case 2
    break;

    default:
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert your switch string to lower or upper case beforehand

```
switch("KEK".ToLower())
{
 case "kek":
  CW("hit!");
  break;
}
```