# Per-String function (IDK how it's called)

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I'm working on my C# project,
and I need to do this, but without the `If`, in a short way;

```
for (String = n) do that
for (String = s) do those
for (String = c) do this
```

I don't know how it's called, or how to do it without the long `If` functions.

Comment: `switch`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06tc147t(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: What logical reason can there be for not using a `if else if else` conditional statement?

Comment: You probably don't want to use a `string` for this in the first place. Jumping ahead, if `String` were an `Action` you could just invoke it.

Comment: @Ramhound - because the IF thingies take A LOT of code lines, which are a mess... As people guided me - Switches are fast, short and WORKING. I had too many bugs using IF statements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *can* simply use a switch statement:

```
switch (myString) {
    case "n":
        //...
        break;
    case "s":
        //...
        break;
    case "c":
        //...
        break;
}
```

But be aware that the used `case`-strings are **constants** and **case-sensitive**!
Be also aware that using `myString.ToLower()` is dangerous!

If case-sensivity is a problem, you have to use `if`s:

```
if (string.Compare(myString, "abc", true)==0)) {
    //...
}
else if (string.Compare(myString, "123", true)==0)) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: "the strings are ... not case-sensitive" (sic). Can you back that statement up please? C# **is** case sensitive for string comparison using `==`, and `switch` is [no](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334134/how-to-make-the-c-sharp-switch-statement-use-ignorecase) [different](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5986694/cs-switch-statement-is-case-sensitive-is-there-a-way-to-toggle-it-so-it-becom)

Comment: @AndyBrown: sorry, my bad!

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was searching for ^_^

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`switch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/06tc147t.aspx), e.g. for a variable called `myString`:

```
switch (myString) {
  case "n":
    doThat();
    break;
  case "s":
    doThose();
    break;
  case "c":
    doThis();
    break;
  default:
    doNothing();
    break;
}
```

The `default` case is there in case your `myString` is none of the values you have taken account of in your specific `case` statements.

Comment: same as Joe said... Thanks!

Comment: @TDT-Alpha. haha, except I answered first ;)

Comment: it is so predicted (NVM, my luck and faith are like this case).. Thank YOU BOTH!!!